# making html web page

Tags: html

I am making a web page with html. I made a choose button that the users can select a file and upload it. I want them to be able to upload a  and if the file that they chose is wrong . Is it possible to do that with html syntax what else I should add more?

Thank you,

Comment: You need server-side code.

Comment: Thank you for replying back. Do you know any example of the same work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP to do that, make the code to upload a file and if the choice is wrong send a PHP header with you status code :

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.1 402 Payment Required"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need server side code, e.g. in php you can use: http://php.net/manual/de/function.http-response-code.php